# Angular is accusing that every name of module I write already exists

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Recently I have updated my Angular from 4 to 6 and now it is blocking to generate everything...

[image]

Below follows my ng --version result

```
C:\Dev\Projetos\****\Desenvolvimento\WEB\vcm-web\src\app>ng --version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 6.1.2
Node: 8.11.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.7.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.7.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.7.2
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.7.2
@angular-devkit/core              0.7.2
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.7.2
@angular/cli                      6.1.2
@ngtools/webpack                  6.1.2
@schematics/angular               0.7.2
@schematics/update                0.7.2
rxjs                              6.2.2
typescript                        2.8.4
webpack                           4.9.2
```

Kindly say me if I need to supply more information.

**UPDATE**

Below is my app.module.ts code. Seems not be wrong

```
import { MateriaisModule } from './components/materiais/materiais.module';
import { RotasModule } from './components/rotas/rotas.module';
import { FabricantesModule } from './components/fabricantes/fabricantes.module';
import { ContratosModule } from './components/contratos/contratos.module';
import { EquipamentosModule } from './components/equipamentos/equipamentos.module';
import { RegionaisModule } from './components/regionais/regionais.module';
import { BasesModule } from './components/bases/bases.module';
import { MunicipiosModule } from './components/municipios/municipios.module';
import { UsuariosModule } from './components/usuarios/usuarios.module';
import { ContratoPesquisaComponent } from './components/contratos/contrato-pesquisa/contrato-pesquisa.component';
import { ContratoCadastroComponent } from './components/contratos/contrato-cadastro/contrato-cadastro.component';
import { EquipamentoPesquisaComponent } from './components/equipamentos/euipamento-pesquisa/equipamento-pesquisa.component';
import { EquipamentoCadastroComponent } from './components/equipamentos/equipamento-cadastro/equipamento-cadastro.component';
import { FabricantePesquisaComponent } from './components/fabricantes/fabricante-pesquisa/fabricante-pesquisa.component';
import { FabricanteCadastroComponent } from './components/fabricantes/fabricante-cadastro/fabricante-cadastro.component';
import { MaterialPesquisaComponent } from './components/materiais/material-pesquisa/material-pesquisa.component';
import { MaterialCadastroComponent } from './components/materiais/material-cadastro/material-cadastro.component';
import { RotaPesquisaComponent } from './components/rotas/rota-pesquisa/rota-pesquisa.component';
import { RotaCadastroComponent } from './components/rotas/rota-cadastro/rota-cadastro.component';
import { RegionalCadastroComponent } from './components/regionais/regional-cadastro/regional-cadastro.component';
import { RegionalPesquisaComponent } from './components/regionais/regional-pesquisa/regional-pesquisa.component';
import { BaseCadastroComponent } from './components/bases/base-cadastro/base-cadastro.component';
import { BasePesquisaComponent } from './components/bases/base-pesquisa/base-pesquisa.component';
import { UsuarioCadastroComponent } from './components/usuarios/usuario-cadastro/usuario-cadastro.component';
import { UsuarioPesquisaComponent } from './components/usuarios/usuario-pesquisa/usuario-pesquisa.component';
import { AutorizacaoFilterService } from './seguranca/autorizacao-filter.service';
// IMPORTS DO ANGULAR
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

// IMPORTS DE TERCEIROS
import { MenuModule } from 'primeng/components/menu/menu';

// IMPORTS DA APLICAÇÃO
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';

import { PaginaNaoEncontradaComponent } from './core/pagina-nao-encontrada.component';
import { LoginFormComponent } from './seguranca/login-form/login-form.component';
import { AlterarSenhaComponent } from './seguranca/alterar-senha/alterar-senha.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginFormComponent },
  { path: 'usuarios', component: UsuarioPesquisaComponent, canActivate: [AutorizacaoFilterService] },
  { path: 'usuarios/novo', component: UsuarioCadastroComponent, canActivate: [AutorizacaoFilterService] },
  { path: 'usuarios/:id', component: UsuarioCadastroComponent, canActivate: [AutorizacaoFilterService] },
  { path: 'alterarSenha', component: AlterarSenhaComponent, canActivate: [AutorizacaoFilterService] },
  { path: 'bases', component: BasePesquisaComponent, canActivate: [AutorizacaoFilterService] },
  { path: 'bases/novo', component: BaseCadastroComponent, canActivate: [AutorizacaoFilterService] },
  { path: 'bases/:id', component: BaseCadastroComponent, canActivate: [AutorizacaoFilterService] },
  { path: 'regionais', component: RegionalPesquisaComponent, canActivate: [AutorizacaoFilterService] },
  { path: 'regionais/novo', component: RegionalCadastroComponent, canActivate: [AutorizacaoFilterService] },
  { path: 'regionais/:id', component: RegionalCadastroComponent, canActivate: [AutorizacaoFilterService] },
  { path: 'contratos', component: ContratoPesquisaComponent, canActivate: [AutorizacaoFilterService] },
  { path: 'contratos/novo', component: ContratoCadastroComponent, canActivate: [AutorizacaoFilterService] },
  { path: 'contratos/:id', component: ContratoCadastroComponent, canActivate: [AutorizacaoFilterService] },
  { path: 'equipamentos', component: EquipamentoPesquisaComponent, canActivate: [AutorizacaoFilterService] },
  { path: 'equipamentos/novo', component: EquipamentoCadastroComponent, canActivate: [AutorizacaoFilterService] },
  { path: 'equipamentos/:id', component: EquipamentoCadastroComponent, canActivate: [AutorizacaoFilterService] },
  { path: 'fabricantes', component: FabricantePesquisaComponent, canActivate: [AutorizacaoFilterService] },
  { path: 'fabricantes/novo', component: FabricanteCadastroComponent, canActivate: [AutorizacaoFilterService] },
  { path: 'fabricantes/:id', component: FabricanteCadastroComponent, canActivate: [AutorizacaoFilterService] },
  { path: 'materiais', component: MaterialPesquisaComponent, canActivate: [AutorizacaoFilterService] },
  { path: 'materiais/novo', component: MaterialCadastroComponent, canActivate: [AutorizacaoFilterService] },
  { path: 'materiais/:id', component: MaterialCadastroComponent, canActivate: [AutorizacaoFilterService] },
  { path: 'rotas', component: RotaPesquisaComponent, canActivate: [AutorizacaoFilterService] },
  { path: 'rotas/novo', component: RotaCadastroComponent, canActivate: [AutorizacaoFilterService] },
  { path: 'rotas/:id', component: RotaCadastroComponent, canActivate: [AutorizacaoFilterService] },
  { path: 'pagina-nao-encontrada', component: PaginaNaoEncontradaComponent, canActivate: [AutorizacaoFilterService] },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'pagina-nao-encontrada' }
];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true}),

    MenuModule,

    CoreModule,
    UsuariosModule,
    MunicipiosModule,
    BasesModule,
    RegionaisModule,
    ContratosModule,
    EquipamentosModule,
    FabricantesModule,
    MateriaisModule,
    RotasModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Without erros in the console. My post have too much code and I cannot apply the chances on it yet.

Here you can see that they aren't on the components directory.

[image]

I have ran the commands as Administrator and nothig. I will restart my computer now.

[image]

Comment: you need to run all your commands on root level directory, moreover can you share your app.module code?

Comment: because i think you already have those file you have to generate.\

Comment: I haven't created `ordemservicoo` module.

Comment: Did you try going to `/src/app/components` and confirming that the files don't exist?

Comment: @JosephWebber yes, even through Explorer. Take a look in the picture that I updated on the post.

Comment: Can you try running the command as admin?

Comment: Have you tried showing hidden files and folders in that directory?

Comment: @JosephWebber The hidden files is being showed and there is nothing.

Comment: @SarhadSalam Yes, see my update plz

Comment: You mentioned you upgradedfrom angular 4 to 6, and after googling a bit I found that sometimes incorrect packages causes weird issues like this. Can you please follow this link and let me know if it helps?
https://www.techiediaries.com/updating-angular-cli-projects/

Before following that, please rollback to your previous version of angular

Comment: Uhm.. Due to my deadlines, I couldn't proceed to investigate. So the faster solution for me was create another project with ng new and migrate my components from the defective project and install the needed dependencies. Ready to work.